# How to display payment method and application in order view Magento 2 Admin?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to display application_no if payment method is FN in order details page.

I have created a block.

```
class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
         array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

}
```

Also, I have created a sales_order_view.xml to display my application_no (Tested it with static value and working fine).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
           <referenceContainer name="payment_additional_info">
                <block class="Limesharp\FinanceNow\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
             </referenceContainer>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is my view file -

`FN: <?php echo $block->getOrder(); ?>`

Now I wanna pass application_no(custom column already in sales_order table) and payment_method. How can I pass this information from block to view of current order and display it conditionally?